# I'm trying to replace a string in a specific line number using a variable

Tags: shell, sed

here's my attempt:

```
sed -i -e "$chs/|0|/|900|/" users
```

The variable "chs" has the line number in which I want to 
replace the string, but it doesn't work, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `chs` contains the line number, say 5, then the following:

```
sed -i -e "$chs/|0|/|900|/" users
```

will expand to:

```
sed -i -e "5/|0|/|900|/" users
```

As a sed command, that is nonsense.  It should return an error message about an `unknown command`.

You need to create a *substitute*  command preceded by a line number.  Try:

```
sed -i -e "$chs s/|0|/|900|/" users
```

Answer (score -1):

awk to the rescue!

```
 awk -v n="$chs" 'NR==n{sub(/search/,replace)}1'
```

Comment: While true, this is not sed